# How do I specify the HEVC codec in the HTML5 video source type attribute?

Tags: html, video, ffmpeg, safari, hevc

I'd like to load and play a smaller HEVC-encoded video on web browsers with support for it.

I'm using this code on Safari 11 (macOS 10.13), which has support for the HEVC format.

```
<video muted playsinline autoplay>
    <source src="clip.webm" type="video/webm; codecs=vp9">
    <source src="clip-hevc.mp4" type="video/mp4; codecs=hevc">
    <source src="clip.mp4" type="video/mp4; codecs=avc1">
    <p>Video not supported</p>
</video>
```

In Web Inspector > Network Panel, I see that Safari loads both `clip.mp4` and `clip-hevc.mp4`. If I inspect the video element, I see that `clip.mp4` is playing, not `clip-hevc.mp4`. I see the same thing on iOS 11.

When I call [`HTMLMediaElement.canPlayType()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canPlayType) on the types I specified, I get

- `maybe` on `video/mp4; codecs=hevc`
- `probably` on `video/mp4; codecs=avc1`
- Nothing on variants of the HEVC codec I've seen (e.g., `hvc1`, `hev1`)

Something else I noticed: When I remove the `clip.mp4` option, `clip-hevc.mp4` downloads and plays just fine!

How can I make sure that only the best supported MP4 variant downloads and plays in the browser?

Comment: have you tried putting the hevc clip first in the list of sources?

Comment: @Offbeatmammal yep, that didn't work

Comment: I'm seeing the same problems. Looks like Apple has not thought this through correctly. I wonder if the webmaster part is a better place for this?

Comment: @CharlieClark good call, reposted [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/113040/how-do-i-specify-the-hevc-codec-in-the-html5-video-source-type-attribute)

Answer (score 4):

FYI found in iOS14 `type="video/mp4; codecs=hevc"` doesn't work anymore. `type="video/mp4"` and `type="video/mp4; codecs=hvc1"` does[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the browser supports hevc code by using this link
https://cconcolato.github.io/media-mime-support/#other_video_codecs

And depending on hevc profile, you must specify the type of codec
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYYa4.png)